# Joomla Developement :: Probleme with URL Rewriting

Tags: php, url, joomla, url-rewriting

I am finalizing the creation of a component for Joomla and I have problems with URL rewriting.

I have created the class "router.php" which is called by the base file of my component, and I use "JRoute" to rewrite my link in SEF.

The problem is that Joomla ignores my component rooter and loads the contents of the native component `com_content`.

for the following url - 
http://lafoliedesvernis.com/vernitheque/revendeurs/2-printemps-haussmann.html - Joomla will show me the article of `com_content` who have `ID = 2` rather than display the record of my component that has `ID = 2`

I feel that I have reached my goal, but for some code somewhere which I can't see. what makes Joomla ignore my router and use the `com_content` router?

Here is the code for my router:

```
<?php
defined ('_JEXEC') or die ('Restricted access');

   VernithequeBuildRoute function (& $ query)
   {
     $ Segments = array ();

     if (isset ($ query ['view'])) {
       $ Segments [0] = $ query ['view'];
         unset ($ query ['view']);
      };

     if (isset ($ query ['id'])) {
           $ Segments [1] = $ query ['id'];
         unset ($ query ['id']);
      };

     return $ segments;
   } / / End function VernithequeBuildRoute

   VernithequeParseRoute function ($ segments)
   {
     $ Vars = array ();

     if (count ($ segments)> 0) {

         $ Vars ['view'] = $ segments [0];
       switch ($ vars ['view']) {
         case 'all':
             $ Catid = explode (':', $ segments [1]);
             $ Vars ['catid'] = (int) $ catid [0];
          break;
         case 'category':
             $ Vars ['id'] = (int) $ segments [1];
          break;
         case 'brand':
             $ Id = explode (':', $ segments [1]);            
             $ Vars ['id'] = (int) $ id [0];       
          break;
         case 'resellers':
             $ Id = explode (':', $ segments [1]);            
             $ Vars ['id'] = (int) $ id [0];       
          break;
         case 'varnish':
             $ Id = explode (':', $ segments [1]);            
             $ Vars ['id'] = (int) $ id [0];       
          break;
         case 'configure':
             $ Id = explode (':', $ segments [1]);            
             $ Vars ['id'] = (int) $ id [0];       
          break;
         box 'panel':
             $ Id = explode (':', $ segments [1]);            
             $ Vars ['id'] = (int) $ id [0];       
          break;

       };

     Else {}
       $ Vars ['view'] = $ segments [0];
     } / / End count (segments) statement

     return $ vars;
   } / / End VernithequeParseRoute
?>
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you call JRoute::_()

Answer (score 0):

So I get a step and I can bring some precisions:

Apparently it's not a "router" problem , I stuted the  "com_content" router, including reference information that (the $ vars array).

In this case the $vars array returned by the "route" of the "com_content" is composed of the index "view" (string), index "id" (int), and the index "catid "(int) if there is one. So I made sure that the "router" in my component returns the same thing, and that the case because if I do a var_dump of $ vars on the landing page I have returned data that appears but the loaded data are those of "com_content", it is indeed an extension problem ! Joomla does not load the correct extension, it will not read the correct table ... so what may come?? the item ID?? the menu link??

If necessary I put the code for JRoute:

```
// Not Working   
    $link = JRoute::_('index.php?view='.$type.''.$catid.'&id='. $slug);
    // also try this but Not Working to   
    $link = JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_vernitheque&view='.$type.''.$catid.'&id='. $slug);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current SEF URL is made up of two parts:

**vernitheque/revendeurs/**  points to the component,

and

**2-printemps-haussmann.html**

identifies the article / item.

Joomla creates the first part based on menu item aliases, NOT component names!
(unless your component has no menu item associated, in which case you would see /component/content)

So check your menus, /vernitheque should be the alias of a first-level menuitem, and possibly revendeurs is the second level for some com_content view.

So create a menu item that points to a view in your component and give it a meaningful alias.

Your SEF urls should now have the new alias as a prefix, and routing should start working again.

If however the generated alias still points to Joomla com_content, this would be very weird: Joomla only allows unique top-level aliases.

I haven't looked deeply into your code, but from the behaviour you describe the issue seems to be outside its scope (it's invoking the wrong component, not passing the wrong parameters)

Comment: The Itemid is not lost between the two page. I find the good "itemid" in the page that appear the com_content article.