# How to remove bits from the url using the htaccess file?

Tags: .htaccess, url, joomla, url-rewriting

Hi I am using joomla for my website and I would like to remove the bits in between my url.

The original URL:
"/calums/index.php/component/jsjobs/jsjobs/employer/"

The way I want it to be:
"/calums/employer/"

It would be great if some one can help me work out how to do it using the htaccess file.

Thanks.

Comment: What version of Joomla! are you using? Also what platform is it hosted on?

Answer (score 0):

first of all you need to enable SEF in Joomla to get rid of the /index.php/ part:

- enable sef in global configuration (the first two checkboxes)
- copy your htaccess.txt to .htaccess

This is transparent and should make your URL look like this:

/calums/component/jsjobs/jsjobs/employer/

Then, by looking at your URL, it appears the component jsjobs doesn't have a menu item associated.  Menu items are associated with views, so you should go into menu manager and add a new menu item and try to setup menu items for jsjobs.  You might not find one that matches exactly but you should be partway there.

Once a menu item is setup (and the cache is cleared) you should begin to see 
/component/jsjobs replaced at a minimum.  If there is no menu item that produces the right url, then you might have to create an .xml file in the component/view folder you desire.  More details in this answer: [Joomla Developement :: Probleme with URL Rewriting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14636402/joomla-developement-probleme-with-url-rewriting/14654862#14654862)

Answer (score -1):

my first answer on stackoverflow. try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(\w)/(\w)/(.*) $1/index.php/component/jsjobs/jsjobs/$2/$3
```